# grease pencil rendering in wrong location

Tags: grease-pencil

I have moved my grease pencil object far in the background but when i render it comes close to the camera. I have several of these lightning objects and they all have this problem. I have attached 2 screen shots. One from the viewport and one of the rendered frame. As you can see the grease pencil is closer to the camera when rendered [image][image]

Comment: Have you tried enabling View Layer-> Passes -> Data-> Include Z ?